# How to Overcome Complex Number in Inverse Cosine

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, 3d

I have values for x,y,z coordinates of two points A and B as in attached figure, my objective is to determine a third point C hence making a triangle. Since I could determine distance values between the points, I tried to obtain the angles BAC and ABC.
However when I used cosine formula, the value I obtained for cosA is not within the range of [-1, 1]. Hence the inverse cosine resulted in Complex number.
How can I avoid or deal with such situation?
Please I will appreciate any guide
[Triangle from the two points A,B and Point C to be determined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awMEj.png)

Comment: As $|AC|>|AB|+|BC|$ your triangle is pure imagination ...

Answer (score 2):

Your linked diagram lists the side lengths of your putative triangle to be
$$|AB| = 10.8, \quad |AC| = 53.12, \quad BC = 11
$$
Here's the problem: those side lengths contradict the triangle inequality. If $x,y,z$ are the lengths of the three sides of a triangle, then the triangle inequality is
$$x  \le y + z
$$
This is violated for $x=|AC|$, $y=|AB|$, $z=|BC|$. So there does not exist any triangle with those side lengths.

Comment: I seem not to understand the rule of triangular inequality. If you are a programmer, please plot the three points A=[ 58.7, 25.8    0.90];  B=[52.5, 78.5, 2.0]; C=[50.3   89.3  4.0]. Hence, |AB|=53.1, |AB|=11.2, |BC|=64.2. I choose the length of |AB| not carefully before but now I have seen it should be as above. I hope this satisfies triangular inequality rule?